# Same card height in boostrap 4 flex row in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have 3 cards in 3 columns in a row in bootstrap 4.
I have set the height of the cards to 100% but only in Safari (MacOSX) it does not work.

I have only set the card height to 100%
Here is the [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/M3vjRDlbmR)

Chrome/IE/FF result:[image: Chrome]

Safari result:
[image: Safari]

Comment: You could try something like this - https://www.bootply.com/G8CtDWNA25 (I would change that col class to include something else so you don't change all cols)

Comment: @Pete, thanks that did the job!